# Duplicate a stream with module-remap-sink?

Tags: pulseaudio

I have a phone for which I use my computer as a headphone through bluetooth. I want to direct the sound from the phone both to a pulseaudio-aware recorder (in fact OBS) and to my physical sound card. (I do not want to record the sound from my physical sound card)

Either this way

```
Bluetooth sink ---->  Virtual sink   ----->  Sound card sink
                          |--> record this sink's monitor
```

or this way

```
               |------> Virtual sink  ---> record monitor
Bluetooth sink |
               |------> Sound card sink
```

I think I could do this with pulseaudio loopback devices (and indeed, pulseaudio autoconfiguration creates one, that I can direct to a virtual sink).

However I read that module-remap-sink can be less computationally intensive (with remix=no). But its semantics is not really clear to me. I tried to fidget with it but without success so far and I find it difficult to get information on it.

Is it usable in my case ?

Answer (score 0):

From looking at the module-remap-sink docs, it looks like module-remap-sink is for rearranging (remapping) the channels (like front-right, front-left, center, etc) of a stream, not for splitting the stream into multiple sinks.

Docs: https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User/Modules/#module-remap-sink

I'm also looking around for a way to split a stream in a simpler way than using loopbacks, but I haven't found one yet.